# Kafka connect SourceTask commit() and commitRecord() methods

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka connect and trying to build an acknowledgement mechanism for my custom JDBC source connector (reading from oracle DB). So, whenever the data gets added to Kafka topic, I want to update the status/offset in my source DB table. The confluent docs for Kafka connect mentions 2 methods: commit and commitRecord for this but states that "The APIs are provided for source systems which have an acknowledgement mechanism for messages" (ref: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html, refer section: "Task Example - Source Task")

1. Does oracle DB supports acknowledgement mechanism?
2. If yes, can we use commit() or commitRecord() to update the status/offset in source DB?
3. How to implement these methods?
4. Can we use the default JDBC source connector for this? (https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html)

Comment: You have full control over what you can read/write to the database, so yes, it supports "acknowledgement". The Confluent one stores either recently read primary ID or timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you want to mark records in source Oracle table that were read? If something was written to Kafka topic it means that it was read from source. In that case you can just use Confluent's `JdbcSourceConnector` with `OracleDatabaseDialect`.

You can of course create the Sink connector which will read from topic and update records in source table, but it art for art's sake.

Comment: I want to mark/acknowledge records in source table so as to ensure consistency and accuracy. Actually the solution cannot afford to lose even one row of data. If Kafka connect reads from source table and fails to write to kafka topic because of any failures, it needs to be known to the source system.

Comment: @JavaDev Then use Debezium or GoldenGate if you cannot miss any events

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will have to explore Debezium or GoldenGate. But following your response that oracle should support acknowledgement, I guess can override commit and commitRecord. Will try that. Thank you!

Comment: One cause might be to implement the outbox pattern where to a particular database many clients can write at once. Then you can't have an incrementing id used as an offset (because the transactions might be committed out-of-order hence you might loose some messages). I'm not that familiar with Kafka Connect but commit()/commitRecord() operation seems to be a place where one would want to mark outbox records as processed.